# Merge pandas DataFrame and return common values with the column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us consider two different pandas dataframes **df1** and **df2** described below. 
This exercise consists of comparing all columns row by row and return the value that is in common in both dataframes, as well as the column name.

Let us give an example for a better understanding. Let us assume the folllowing dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[23,12,44],[34,55,33]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[11,12,43],[10,51,34]], columns = ['D', 'E', 'F'])
```

The result of the operation should be:

```
   col   value
0   E    12
1   F    34
```

Is it possible to do it in an efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to get the columns to rows, and after that do an [`inner merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1_melt = df1.melt(value_vars=df1.columns, var_name='Cols')
df2_melt = df2.melt(value_vars=df2.columns, var_name='Cols')

df_final = pd.merge(df2_melt, df1_melt, on='value', suffixes=['', '_1']).drop('Cols_1', axis=1)

print(df_final)
  Cols  value
0    E     12
1    F     34
```

**Edit**: Intermediate melted tables look like this:

```
print(df1_melt, '\n')
print(df2_melt)

  Cols  value
0    A     23
1    A     34
2    B     12
3    B     55
4    C     44
5    C     33 

  Cols  value
0    D     11
1    D     10
2    E     12
3    E     51
4    F     43
5    F     34
```

Comment: clever answer. I had used the mode, but this is much better.

Comment: Thanks, for most of the problems there is an pandas/numpys solution for it, just have to know the method/function to use. @NunodeSousa